# python read from chinese file err

Tags: python, io

I make read from chinese
but ,it didn't run normally
The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#read from file 
file=open('temp2','rb',encoding='utf-8')
lines=file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line)


file.close()
```

this file content is below:
http://www.sina.com.cn/intro/copyright.shtml

```
新浪新闻
国内、国际。
国内、国际。
```

Comment: Help me,pleasea

Comment: What is not running normally? Could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: @secnoodle is the reading not working or the printing?

Comment: The result like below:

E:\python_workspace3\sublime>python io03.py
b'http://www.sina.com.cn/intro/copyright.shtml\r\n'
b'\xe6\x96\xb0\xe6\xb5\xaa\xe6\x96\xb0\xe9\x97\xbb\r\n'
b'\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe5\x86\x85\xe3\x80\x81\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe3\x80\x82\r\
b'\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe5\x86\x85\xe3\x80\x81\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe3\x80\x82\r\
b'\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe5\x86\x85\xe3\x80\x81\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe3\x80\x82'

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? if you are reading the file with 'rb', you should get an error `ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`. If you change the line as `file=open('temp', 'r', encoding='utf8')`, then everything works unless your file is saved as binary.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `utf-8` to `utf8`. `-` is not needed.
Also, please change `rb` to `r` if the text file is not saved in binary format.

Comment: It didn't help ,too.  Thank you all the same.